# can someone please explain this pseudocode for me?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i do
       print “hello world”
    end for
end for
```

I don't understand what `to` and `do` mean and what exactly this code does. The question was, how often is "hello world" printed out when `n = 4`. Is the answer 10? How do I work this out?

Comment: 1+2+3+4 = 10......get it?

Comment: no? can you explain in abit more detail?

Comment: This is pseudocode. It's meant to be as close to English as possible. If you just read it out loud, it should make sense. For i equal to 1 to n do... just means "for each `i` from 1 to n, do..."

Comment: Have you tried to understand loop first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer Loop:

```
for i = 1 to n do
```

(initially `i` will be assigned to 1)

this loop is saying that something has to be done n times (meaning of to). What has to be done is written in your inner loop (meaning of do).

```
for j = 1 to i do
       print “hello world”
```

For each value of i, the inner loop will be executed `i` times (this is because each time when `i` changes, your inner loop will be executed `i` times `(for j = 1 to i do)`). Here, it will print `hello world` each time.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 3):

Lets break down for innermost loop `j = 1 to i`

```
i = 1
you will see only one hello world

i =2
2 hello world

i = 3
3 hello world

i =4
4 hello world
```

So total  `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10`  *hello worlds*

For n = 10

```
1 + 2 + 3 .... = 10 = 55 hello worlds
```

for n = k

```
Sum of Arithmetic Progression:  k * (k + 1 ) /2 hello worlds  printed
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that at the first iteration of the outer loop,the inner loop gets executed one time , then at the second iteration two times and so forth.So 1+2+3+4 = 10

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called nested loops:

- Assign with i = 1 and loop (in every iteration add 1 to i so it becomes 2,3,4,..n) and in every iteration do these steps:

  - Assign j = 1 and loop (in every iteration add 1 to j so it becomes 2,3,4,..i until it is equal to i) and in every iteration do these steps:
  - => print hello